# getPageSource is not working for RSelenium

Tags: parsing, web-scraping, data-binding, scrape, rselenium

My goal is to retrieve information about the reviews which are located on different pages. I created a csv file with URL for every page and set each row as a destination for navigation of remotedriver. I created a loop for Selenium which was supposed to visit all this urls and retrieve needed nodes. After that
I created a loop for retrieving html page nodes and making unified dataframe out of this (via combining the result of each iteration in the loop with df with the same names of columns - was created before).

Actually i did this two month ago but now I am able to get only page source for the first page but not the next. At the same time the remotedriver is navigating the pages smoothly (it means URLs are alright!)

Example of the code:

```
uuu<-read.csv("/Users/uuu.csv")

data<-data.frame(title=character(),
             date_travel=character(),
             grades=character())

####starting selenium####
rd<-rsDriver(remoteServerAddr = "localhost", browser = "firefox", port=9353L)
for (i in 1:nrow(uuu)){
tryCatch({
url<-uuu$url[i]
cd<-rd$client
cd$navigate(url)
 Sys.sleep(2)


 reviews2<-read_html(cd$getPageSource()[[1]])

title<-reviews2 %>%
  html_nodes(".ocfR3SKN") %>%
  html_text()


date_travel<-reviews2 %>%
  html_nodes("._34Xs-BQm") %>%
  html_text()
   try(
  {
    record_url<-data.frame(title,
                           date_travel))
 }
  , silent = T
)
 try(
  {
    data <- bind_rows(data, record_url)
  }
  , silent = T
)

Sys.sleep(2)
})
}
```

The result of the parsing - seems like that he managed to get only the page source of the first urlbut not the others. However RD was navigating them.[image: The result - only first URLs but nor the others]`

Comment: Side note: You have one too many ) in `record_url<-data.frame(title,
                               date_travel))`. When will you add grades? And what happens without the trys?

Comment: @QHarr Thank you for your comment!

Additional characteristics as  grades, route, flight and etc are also in the code (in the same place where title and date) I just did not add in order to save more space. Without trys and this additional bracket (thanks for that!) here is what i got:
- "Error in data.frame(title, date_travel, grades, route, flight, class,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 5
In addition: There were 24 warnings (use warnings() to see them)"

Looks like there is a problem of reading the page sources of next URLs, I do not know why...

Comment: Print the status code during loop?

Comment: @QHarr if i got you correctly, I added this line  "status_code(reviews2)" after this "reviews2<-read_html(cd$getPageSource()[[1]])" but got error:
     
 "Error in UseMethod("status_code") : 
  no applicable method for 'status_code' applied to an object of class "c('xml_document', 'xml_node')"

Comment: No. It is a my bad. You are using selenium for the navigation and you have already said you can see it visiting the right pages.

Comment: Have you verified your selectors for each page and is a longer wait condition needed?

Comment: @QHarr, nope. How is it possible to do?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232198/discussion-between-sergey-kolesnik-and-qharr).